# How can I make a form label keyboard accessible?

Tags: jquery, html, accessibility

I have an HTML5 form that collects some information and processes it when the user submits the form.  It uses the jQuery Validation Plugin to validate the inputs and, if there are errors, it shows an error-message-container div at the top of the screen containing a list of errors, and then gives it focus so the screen reader reads them all out.  This is implemented using `<label for="input id with error">` so when the user clicks on the label with a mouse the input with the error gets focus.  Like this:

```
<form id="ts-qqw-form" action="#" method="post">
    <div tabindex="-1" class="error-message-container ts-hidden" id="error-message-container">
        <p>The following errors have occurred:</p>
        <ul>
            <li><label for="TravellerAge_1">Please provide the age of the travellers.</label></li>
        </ul>
        <!-- ... -->
    </div>
    <div class="ts-qqw-section clearfix">
        <h4>Who</h4>

        <div class="ts-qqw-question">
            <label for="ts-travellers-num">Number of travellers</label>
        </div>
        <!-- traveller number selection -->
        <div class="ts-qqw-input">
            <select name="InsuranceStepA_PeopleCount" id="ts-travellers-num">
                <option selected="selected" value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="ts-qqw-question">
            <span>Age of travellers</span>
        </div>
        <!-- traveller ages inputs -->
        <div class="ts-qqw-input ts-age" id="ts-age-container">
            <input name="TravellerAge_1" class="ts-hidden ts-numeric field-error" id="TravellerAge_1" type="text" maxlength="2" data-validation-group="age">
            <input name="TravellerAge_2" class="ts-numeric" id="TravellerAge_2" type="text" maxlength="2" data-validation-group="age">
            <input name="TravellerAge_3" class="ts-hidden ts-numeric" id="TravellerAge_3" style="display: none;" type="text" maxlength="2" data-validation-group="age">
        </div>
        <!-- ... -->
    </div>
    <div class="ts-qqw-section clearfix">
        <div class="ts-qqw-box clearfix">
            <div class="submitButton right">
                <button class="primary-cta ts-qqw-submit" type="submit">Get a quote</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

It works perfectly with the mouse but isn't keyboard accessible (i.e. using the tab key) at all!  This is a problem with the HTML5 label element not receiving focus.  I could just use jQuery to give every label a tabindex="0" but I think I'm missing something. How can I get it so I don't have to use the mouse? The code in the error-message-container div was generated by the jQuery Validation Plugin, so it'll probably be too difficult to re-write it to use `<a>` tags.

I have searched for an answer in SO and checked possible duplicates but without any luck.  Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Thanks, Michael.

Comment: Try the [``tabindex`` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex)

Comment: I used `$("#error-message-container label").each( function() {$(this).attr('tabindex', 0)} );` and when I press tab they get an outline in both MSIE and FF, but neither [Enter] nor [Spacebar] select the element.  Interestingly is I turn on JAWS screen reader with MSIE, JAWS intercepts the key presses and it works as desired with only the keyboard.  I tried to add a JS onclick handler but it was a failure too.  :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is totally flawed. You should change the way you are doing this completely:

1. Labels need to be visually close to the input fields that they
   label,
2. Visible labels need to be provided for all inputs at all times and not only when there is an error and these labels must be semantically associated with their input fields
3. Labels are the wrong semantic element for the click behavior, the correct element is a link. Just use a link.

Take a look at the following implementation for a good markup of labels and errors

http://dylanb.github.io/bower_components/a11yfy/examples/form-validation.html

You can also look at this presentation for the techniques to use

http://www.slideshare.net/dylanbarrell/accessible-dynamic-forms-27169766

Comment: NB: I'm not the author (he's long gone), I'm the maintainer.  Although the jQuery Validation Plugin was used to implement the validation, it turns out the jQuery code to create a label and put it in the error div was in the code I was trying to maintain, so I changed it to create a link instead. This is now keyboard accessible.

Answer (score 0):

The label is inside a div with a tabindex of -1, which means it can only be reached via script not by keyboard. Also every input should have a label to begin with, they're intended to describe the input not as a presentation container for errors. See http://simplyaccessible.com/article/error-messages-in-labels/ for a better way to mark up errors and labels.